# Output a Cirq gate as a Numpy array?

Tags: programming, cirq

How do I output a Cirq gate as a Numpy array? For example, I would like to print a Pauli X gate `cirq.X` as

```
numpy.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by calling `cirq.unitary`.

```
>>> import cirq
>>> cirq.unitary(cirq.X)
array([[0.+0.j, 1.+0.j],
       [1.+0.j, 0.+0.j]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Compared to Qiskit, I found Cirq has very little documentation. Do you have any recommendation for getting familiar with Cirq?

Comment: @user3886914 Which types of documentation do you feel are missing? E.g. there's a decent API reference at readthedocs, but not a lot of task-oriented content like a guided tutorial to do goal X.

Comment: @CraigGidney Compared to Qiskit, I feel that Cirq's tutorial and documents are too short. (Though, I just realized ```cirq.unitary()``` is mentioned in the tutorial page, so that's my bad.) Also, details of the API are sometimes located only in their source code, so I found it a bit difficult to learn Cirq. I think extensive tutorial videos on Youtube would be very helpful.